# is that possible to use webbrowser properties to make http requests?

Tags: browser, httprequest

in the app's main window there's a webbrowser control with a page that requires authentication already logged on. is it possible to use the control (header, cookies...) to make a http request so i can update some other components without navigating directly from the webbrowser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an AJAXy request.